# Ncurses program is exiting without even creating a window

Tags: c, linux, gnu, ncurses

I wrote a simple C flashcard program; it takes a filename as its second argument and this file is then read line-by-line and using ncurses, the question is shown to the user, on pressing enter she is shown the answer, pressing again refreshes the ncurses window so that the next line is read. The file that is read is a simple TSV (though I've written it so that it can be any delimiter). Here's the file, titled  *f.c*:

*Note: I used readline(), a non-C-standard function, because this is a personal project that I'll only ever be using on POSIX systems, so the headache of properly managing memory with fgets just wasn't worth it*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define DELIM "\t"

int count_occ(char* string, char* val)
{
    int count = 0;
    const char* tmp = string;

    while(tmp = strstr(tmp, val))
    {
        count++;
        tmp++;
    }
    return count;
}

bool valid_file(FILE* stream)
{
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len;

    while(getline(&line, &len, stream) != -1)
    {
        if(count_occ(line, DELIM) != 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File name must be supplied\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(!access(argv[1], F_OK) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File supplied in second argument does not exist\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE* stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
    if(!valid_file(stream))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File supplied is not properly formatted: a line is missing a set of delimited values or too many fields were noticed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }
    
    initscr();
    noecho();
    raw();
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t len;

    while(getline(&line, &len, stream) != -1)
    {
        char* qn = strtok(line, DELIM);
        char* ans = strtok(NULL, DELIM);
        char c;
        printw("Question:\n\t%s\nAnswer:\n\t...\n\n", qn);
        while((c = getch()) != 10);
        refresh();
        move(0, 0);

        printw("Question:\n\t%s\nAnswer:\n\t%s\n\n", qn, ans);
        while((c = getch()) != 10);
        refresh();
        move(0, 0);
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using:

```
gcc f.c -o fc -lncurses
```

..with the correct libraries installed, of course.

I then used this file, test.txt, as a sample:

```
What is my name?    Teddy Roosevolt
What is my name?    Teddy Roosevolt
Where am I from?    USA
What is my ethnicity?   Caucasian
What is my nationality? British
What is my name?    Teddy Roosevolt
Where am I from?    USA
What is my ethnicity?   Caucasian
What is my nationality? British
What is my name?    Teddy Roosevolt
Where am I from?    USA
What is my ethnicity?   Caucasian
What is my nationality? British
Where am I from?    USA
What is my ethnicity?   Caucasian
What is my nationality? British
```

Then I ran it with:

```
./fc test.txt
```

And I got nothing - not even an error, not anything at all. Instead,the program ran immediately and exited straight away. I tested it out on poorly formatted files before I tested it out on error-less flashcard files - the poorly formatted ones raise all the right errors, which tells me that the reason it isn't working isn't to do with the block of code at the start of the main file checking whether the file is valid - I think it has to do with the ncurses part - but I can't tell what.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know that Roosevolt isn't British, it's just that I am, and the original "test.txt" was a quiz  on my personal information, so I find-and-replaced any information I didn't want shared.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: You should always check the return value of `fopen`. Just because the file existed during the call to `access`, doesn't mean `fopen` won't fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its quite simple really, and has nothing to do with ncurses:

You never rewind your file!

Your `valid_file` function reads all the data in your file, leaving nothing for the loop in `main`.

Since you never reset the file position after that function, the loop in `main` is never executed as there is nothing for `readline` left to read, and your program ends.

You must add `fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_SET);` to the end of `valid_file` just before `return true`.

Also note, that you never `free` the memory `readline` allocates for you, which you must do after each call, and also reset the `line` pointer to NULL and `len` to 0, to get it to allocate a new buffer.

Otherwise you will end up with a memory leak.
It may not be noticeable if your text file is small, but this is still a bad programming practice!

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you :) I've added fseek, used free(line), line = NULL and len = 0 every time I used getline, it's worked perfectly.